# Login form in AngularJS with Json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, forms-authentication

I'm new in Angular and I am studying the login form.

The model I'm using is this: [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mvrte4?p=preview). There two problems that I'm not able to solve.

- **FIRST**: I don't know how to convert the modal window in a stand-alone page. You can find the modal code in "*parentController*.js":

  ```
  $scope.modalShown = false;
  var showLoginDialog = function() {
  if(!$scope.modalShown){
      $scope.modalShown = true;
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl : 'login.html',
          controller : "LoginCtrl",
          backdrop : 'static',
      });

      modalInstance.result.then(function() {
          $scope.modalShown = false;
      });
  }
  };
  ```
- **SECOND**: In the login form, which is in the "*login.html*" file, you can notice the username *div*:

  ```
  <div style="margin-top: 25px" class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
     </span> 
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"
      ng-model="credentials.username" placeholder="Username" required />
  </div>
  ```

  How can I insert a <*select*> box instead of the input, filled with the usernames in the array (in this case a <*select* box with "Admin, Editor, Guest")?

Thank you very much!

Comment: for the select read the angular docs for the select directive

Comment: What do you mean with "converting the modal window in a stand-alone page"? You want to ditch the modal and show the login in another state or what?

Comment: I have to do a indipendent page, with its own <html></html> tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First : do you want to get rid of  Model window ?

Second : ng-repeat should do

```
<select >
   <option ng-repeat="type in userArray" value="{{type}}" >
        {{type}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have to do a indipendent page, with its own <html> tag!